# I want to use interrupts in 32 bit PIC microcontroller.i'm getting output in MPLAB simulator but can not get it on my Explorer 16 kit

Tags: c, embedded, pic, interrupt-handling

I'm using PIC32MX575F256L microcontroller. This is a simple program to turn on and turn of LED's connected to lower 8 bits of port A using a simple switch as external interrupt:

```
#include<p32xxxx.h>
#include<plib.h>

void __ISR(3,ipl4) EXTInterrupthandller(void)   // interrupt handler
{
    PORTAINV = 0x0ff;   //toggle lower 8 bits of port A (LEDs)
    IFS0CLR = 0x00000800;   //clear the interrupt flag
}

main()
{
    DDPCONbits.JTAGEN = 0;
    TRISA= 0;       // set port A as output port
    TRISESET = 0x0200;  // set external interrupt pin as input pin
    PORTA = 0;      // initially LEDs are off
    IEC0CLR = 0x00000800;   // disable INT3
    IPC0SET = 0x10000000;   // set priority and sub priority of interrupt
    INTCONCLR = 0x00000004; // clear the bit for falling edge trigger
    IFS0CLR = 0x00000800;   // clear the interrupt flag
    INTEnableSystemSingleVectoredInt(); // configure system to handle single vector interrupts
    IEC0SET = 0x00000800;   // enable INT3
    while(1);   // main loop
}
```

Comment: Do the LEDs change at all on the hardware? If you have a simple switch attached to INT it will most likely generate multiple interrupts due to switch bounce.

Comment: I have no PIC32MX575F256L board at hand so I can hardly test your code, but hard-coding all the register values is a sure way of producing unreadable and most likely buggy software.

Comment: Line `IEC0SET = 0x00000800;   // enable INT3` : according to the datasheet, setting bit 11 of `IEC0`enables external interrupt INT2, not INT3. INT3 is bit 15 of `IEC0`. Same thing for `IFS0`